# Load only a few values from complex JSON object in Pig Latin

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a complex JSON file that looks like this: http://pastebin.com/4UfadbqS

I would like to load only several values from these JSON objects using Pig Latin. I tried doing that like this:

```
mydata = LOAD 'data.json' 
    USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, created_at:chararray, 
                      user: {(language:chararray)}’);
STORE mydata 
    INTO 'output';
```

But it seems that Pig Latin is just taking the first 3 values from the JSON and saving them (it does not recognize the column name as a key). Is there a way to achieve this? OR should I just list ALL the values from JSON in a Pig and filter them after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems in the above approach
1. JsonLoader will always expect the full schema of your input but you gave only three fields.
2. JsonLoader will always expect the entire input as a single line but your input is multiline.
3. JsonLoader will not support nested schema but your input contains nested schema.

To solve all the above problems you have use the thirdparty library `elephant-bird jar`.
Download the (**elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar and elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar**) jar file from this link
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/e/elephant.htm and try the below approach

I copied your entire input and formatted as a single line as below.

**input.json**

```
{"filter_level":"medium","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":488927960280211456,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Tue Jul 15 06:08:04 +0000 2014","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"RT @BulleyBufton: @MinaANDMaya PLEASE RT /VOTE BULLEY. Last day to help me win my old rescue @HilbraesDogs £5k https://t.co/Y8g47fLYY1 http\u2026","contributors":null,"retweeted_stt
atus":{"filter_level":"low","contributors":null,"text":"@MinaANDMaya PLEASE RT /VOTE BULLEY. Last day to help me win my old rescue @HilbraesDogs £5k https://t.co/Y8g47fLYY1 httpp
://t.co/DDco9wVXtP","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":"MinaANDMaya","possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","entities":{"trends":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"expanded_url":"https://www.animalfriendsquote.co.uk/fb-worldcup/","indices":[93,116],"display_url":"animalfriendsquote.co.uk/fb-worldcup/","url":"https://t.co/Y8g47fLYY1"}],"hashtags":[],"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":455},"large":{"w":706,"resize":"fit","h":946},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":803}},"id":488926730481332224,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BskERVuIcAAJZGu.jpg","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BskERVuIcAAJZGu.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/BulleyBufton/status/488926827394904064/photo/1","indices":[117,139],"id_str":"488926730481332224","type":"photo","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/DDco9wVXtP","url":"http://t.co/DDco9wVXtP"}],"user_mentions":[{"id":132204038,"name":"Mina*Bad Yoga Kitty*","indices":[0,12],"screen_name":"MinaANDMaya","id_str":"132204038"},{"id":2308374684,"name":"Julianna Kaminski","indices":[75,88],"screen_name":"HilbraesDogs","id_str":"2308374684"}]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":488926827394904064,"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>","in_reply_to_user_id_str":"132204038","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":6,"created_at":"Tue Jul 15 06:03:34 +0000 2014","in_reply_to_user_id":132204038,"favorite_count":3,"id_str":"488926827394904064","place":null,"user":{"location":"CHICAGO , USA","default_profile":false,"statuses_count":8868,"profile_background_tile":true,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"AD54E8","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/225136520/1403608773","id":225136520,"following":null,"favourites_count":5082,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"3D1957","verified":false,"description":"I'm Bulley, I'm proof that there is always hope.\r\nI was in rescue kennels in UK for 9yrs. @ada_bscakes took me in.\r\nWe've moved to America to start a new life.","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"BULLEY","profile_background_color":"0A0A0A","created_at":"Fri Dec 10 19:55:17 +0000 2010","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":3421,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486614595457789952/gtcLac9w_normal.jpeg","geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000166829702/isbjd7O4.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000166829702/isbjd7O4.jpeg","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":-39600,"time_zone":"International Date Line West","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":3702,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"7AC3EE","screen_name":"BulleyBufton","id_str":"225136520","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486614595457789952/gtcLac9w_normal.jpeg","listed_count":29,"is_translator":false},"coordinates":null},"geo":null,"entities":{"trends":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"expanded_url":"https://www.animalfriendsquote.co.uk/fb-worldcup/","indices":[111,134],"display_url":"animalfriendsquote.co.uk/fb-worldcup/","url":"https://t.co/Y8g47fLYY1"}],"hashtags":[],"media":[{"sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"resize":"crop","h":150},"small":{"w":340,"resize":"fit","h":455},"large":{"w":706,"resize":"fit","h":946},"medium":{"w":600,"resize":"fit","h":803}},"id":488926730481332224,"media_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BskERVuIcAAJZGu.jpg","media_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BskERVuIcAAJZGu.jpg","expanded_url":"http://twitter.com/BulleyBufton/status/488926827394904064/photo/1","source_status_id_str":"488926827394904064","indices":[139,140],"source_status_id":488926827394904064,"id_str":"488926730481332224","type":"photo","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/DDco9wVXtP","url":"http://t.co/DDco9wVXtP"}],"user_mentions":[{"id":225136520,"name":"BULLEY","indices":[3,16],"screen_name":"BulleyBufton","id_str":"225136520"},{"id":132204038,"name":"Mina*Bad Yoga Kitty*","indices":[18,30],"screen_name":"MinaANDMaya","id_str":"132204038"},{"id":2308374684,"name":"Julianna Kaminski","indices":[93,106],"screen_name":"HilbraesDogs","id_str":"2308374684"}]},"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"488927960280211456","user":{"location":"","default_profile":false,"statuses_count":1370,"profile_background_tile":true,"lang":"zh-tw","profile_link_color":"038544","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2272804116/1404662156","id":2272804116,"following":null,"favourites_count":2000,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"description":"No More Sorrow","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"Winnie","profile_background_color":"14DBBA","created_at":"Thu Jan 02 10:13:01 +0000 2014","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":311,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/478106512083017728/4ao_8JjE_normal.jpeg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/431815421189029888/YrRNpUfd.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/431815421189029888/YrRNpUfd.jpeg","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":455,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","screen_name":"winnie341881","id_str":"2272804116","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/478106512083017728/4ao_8JjE_normal.jpeg","listed_count":0,"is_translator":false}}
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

A = LOAD 'input.json ' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myMap#'id' AS ID,myMap#'created_at' AS createdAT,myMap#'user' AS User;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(488927960280211456,Tue Jul 15 06:08:04 +0000 2014,[location#,default_profile#false,profile_background_tile#true,statuses_count#1370,lang#zh-tw,profile_link_color#038544,profile_banner_url#https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2272804116/1404662156,id#2272804116,following#,protected#false,favourites_count#2000,profile_text_color#333333,contributors_enabled#false,description#No More Sorrow,verified#false,name#Winnie,profile_sidebar_border_color#000000,profile_background_color#14DBBA,created_at#Thu Jan 02 10:13:01 +0000 2014,default_profile_image#false,followers_count#311,geo_enabled#false,profile_image_url_https#https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/478106512083017728/4ao_8JjE_normal.jpeg,profile_background_image_url#http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/431815421189029888/YrRNpUfd.jpeg,profile_background_image_url_https#https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/431815421189029888/YrRNpUfd.jpeg,follow_request_sent#,url#,utc_offset#,time_zone#,notifications#,friends_count#455,profile_use_background_image#true,profile_sidebar_fill_color#DDEEF6,screen_name#winnie341881,id_str#2272804116,profile_image_url#http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/478106512083017728/4ao_8JjE_normal.jpeg,is_translator#false,listed_count#0])
```

In `elephantbird library` all the values will be `stored as key/value pair(ie MAP datatype)`, so it will be easy to extract the required fields from the loaded data.

In the above pigscript i have extracted the value of `'id','created_at' and 'user'` as per your need.
Suppose you want to extract some fields from 'user' data( `ex: 'friends_count' and 'followers_count'`), in that case you need to project the `'user'` field and extract the required data. sample code below.

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

A = LOAD 'input.json ' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 'user' AS User;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE User#'friends_count', User#'followers_count';
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(455,311)
```