# How do I read in array of integers using JsonLoader in Pig Script?

Tags: arrays, json, apache-pig

I have a JSON file which has the following line in it

```
"helpful": [
    5,
    5
]
```

How do I read this in using a pig script without using any 3rd party library like *elephant-bird* which has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27902425/2534513).

Closed ticket [PIG-2949](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2949) show that support for such operation was added in pig version  0.15.0  but I am not sure to get the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had some doubts about the syntax, this worked:

```
reviews = load 'filename.json'
          using JsonLoader('helpful:{t:(i:int)}');

dump reviews;
```